# Android: Start new activity, when timer reaches 0

Tags: android, android-activity, countdowntimer

I have a countdown timer, When it reaches 00:00 I wish to start a new activity. However the app crashes when the timer reaches 00:00. I tried using the same way to start an activity as I do with buttons and they work but not on timer end.

```
public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer 
{
    Context mContext;

    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) 
    {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }


    public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) 
    {
        gameTimer.setText ( formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        counter.cancel();
        startActivity(new Intent(Game.this, EndGame.class));
    }

}
```

Comment: If the app crashes then there must be a stacktrace in the logcat

Comment: There is nothing in logcat regarding the onFinish(), Thats the problem if it's empty the program just sits with the timer on 00:01

Comment: If there is no logcat, then try logging in each line to identify which line of code causes the crash. Then we can target and correct that particular LOC!

Comment: It's OK i forgot to state the activity in the manifest. But thanks for you time anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your activity is listed under Manifest file and if possible then paste the stacktrace, this will give the clear view of the issue.